# Is it possible to use Google Maps as basemap in ArcGIS for Deskrop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-maps, arcgis-10.3

I remember using an AddIn Earlier that enabled the use of Google Maps within ArcGIS as basemap but I don’t have it now.

I am out of date here, but is it possible (in ArcGIS 10.3) to do that as a built-in functionality and if not, can someone please point me to any tool that would provide this functionality.

Note:
Older answers suggested using  ArcBruTile , but its not realy showing Google Maps, it is however very good in using Bing Maps, OpenStreet ...etc.

Its now ArcGIS 10.3 and I was hoping that someone out there may have developed something new or a workaround to get google maps into ArcGIS for free.

Comment: Indeed it used to be an out of the box functionality to add Google maps within ArcGIS as a basemap but since esri released their own basemaps they removed the feature. But if you got an mxd with Google maps from a previous version it still works

Comment: To attract attention to questions that have been asked before there is advice on [Meta GIS SE](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/what-should-i-do-if-my-question-was-asked-but-there-is-no-accepted-answer-for-t).  In this case I think you are trying to exploit a licensing issue that Google closed off long ago.

Comment: looking it up it seems you right and licencing concerns are the limitation just as Mac answered. This would end my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using http://www.arc2earth.com/ for more than 5 years and have found that to be the easiest way to add Google Map layers to ArcGIS. It is available via subscription.

I don't know of any free tools and that would be unlikely because of the licencing concerns.

Comment: thank you. I will give arc2earth a try, they have a free trial but its $590 a year. I was hoping for a free solution though. I forgot to mention free in my question (by bad) I edited the question.